# standard deviation of a rate of phone calls

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to implement some real time monitoring. I have a real time data feed from which I can calculate the number of phone calls received in the last hour (now-60 minutes). I want to alert when this rate is more than 2 standard deviation from the mean rate.  As some hours in the day will naturally have a higher rate than others I want to make this specific to the time of day.

Would the maths below achieve this or have I made any errors / is there a more appropriate way to handle data like this.

- 1) work out the number of calls per hour
- 2) find standard deviation for each hour
- 3) set threshold at mean for the hour plus two standard deviations

Thanks,
Dan

Heres my sample table (this might not display very well!)

table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}

Hour of day
  # Calls Received day 1
  # Calls Received day 2
  # Calls Received day 3
  Mean
  Standard deviation
  Alert threshold

  


  9 - 10
  10   
  11
  14
  11.7
  1.7
  15.1

  

  10 - 11
  15
  15
  17
  15.7
  0.9
  17.6     


  11 - 12
  18   
  19
  18
  18.3
  0.5  
  19.3


  12 - 13
  12
  10
  8
  10.0
  1.6  
  13.3 


  13 - 14
  10
  11
  10
  11.7 
  2.4
  16.4

Comment: if you can say something about the distribution of the number of calls (e.g. Poisson), that would make derivation much easier

Comment: What you did seems right to me.